# Give name to build steps - Jenkins configuration

Tags: build, hudson, build-process, jenkins

Do you know of a way / a plug-in to better separate different build steps in Jenkins projects?
I used to work with Quickbuild and there I can give a name to each step and in the log I can see which step is currently running.

I have a project that invokes several ant scripts and on failures, I want to catch the exact execution that caused it (so I want to somehow see the step name in the logger).

Thanks,
Or.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add `echo " ---- step N ---- "` at the start of each step :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ant builder, instead of "exec a shell script"/"exec a batch file", it records each ant task as it is run.